# Angular 2 app creating a shadow tag under my page

Tags: angular, shadow-dom

My angular 2 app is creating a `shadow` tag and adding a block under my page and pushing my page content up. I tried deleting the tag but it still persists. Its happening for all my angular 2 projects. In this project its taking my sidebar color and is visible.when i try to remove the sidebar it still there. Why is it created?? How do i remove it?? I added a screenshot of the issue.

[image: devtools screenshot showing DOM tree]

Comment: are you using viewenacapuslation this shadow tag is used for dom manipulation

Comment: It looks like a padding on body or your page parent tag.

Comment: It's there for the newly created project too.